# Errors when using Mac Excel macro to export CSV

Tags: excel, vba, macos, csv

Mac Excel v16.16.7 - Trying to use a macro to export the active sheet of an xlsm file to a csv with the sheet name as the file name.

I'm aware of the sandboxing issues and thought I was getting around them with GrantAccessToMultipleFiles, but the exact macro below delivers three different outcomes:

1. Sometimes it works. Saves the sheet as a CSV in the same directory as the workbook.
2. 400 error
3. Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

```
Sub SaveAsCSV()

    Dim strName As String
    Dim fileAccessGranted As Boolean
    Dim filePermissionCandidates

    filePermissionCandidates = Array(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveSheet.Name & ".csv")

    fileAccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates)

    If fileAccessGranted = True Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        strName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveSheet.Name & ".csv"

        ActiveSheet.Copy    'copy the sheet as a new workbook
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        MsgBox "File has been Created and Saved as:  " & vbCr & strName, , "Copy & Save Report"

    End If

End Sub
```

I'm hoping for some insight into why the outcomes are varied. Thanks!

Comment: At which line do you get the '1004' error?

Comment: I can't recreate your errors, though I'm on windows. Although I had problems with`fileAccessGranted = GrantAccessToMultipleFiles(filePermissionCandidates)` and deleting the file permissions check made it run without issue. You might be having similar issuess.

Comment: @Wizhi I receive the 1004 error at ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, when it happens. But like I said, sometimes it works fine! I send the workbook with the macro to my coworker and they exclusively get the 400 error.